# C - The %x format specifier

Tags: c, string, security, format

I have a small question.  I know that the %x format specifier can be used to read values from the stack in a format string attack.

I found the following code:

```
%08x%08x%08x%08x
```

What does the 08 mean?  What is it doing exactly?  Thanks :)

Comment: Field width of 8 characters, shorter numbers prefixed with leading zeros to match the field width, e.g. `000007ac` or `0005ceef`.

Comment: Which function is this talking about? You say "read values", but all answers seem to assume `printf()` is being used.

Comment: @unwind good point. we all writing for printf.

Comment: Silly me.  Yes, I was referring to the use of this code within the printf function.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Break-down:

- `8` says that you want to show 8 digits
- `0` that you want to prefix with `0`'s instead of just blank spaces
- `x` that you want to print in lower-case hexadecimal.

Quick example (thanks to Grijesh Chauhan):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int data = 29;
    printf("%x\n", data);    // just print data
    printf("%0x\n", data);   // just print data ('0' on its own has no effect)
    printf("%8x\n", data);   // print in 8 width and pad with blank spaces
    printf("%08x\n", data);  // print in 8 width and pad with 0's

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1d
1d
      1d
0000001d
```

Also see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ for reference.

Comment: Added an example hope you like. IF not you can revert back to your version

Comment: @Matthew you should also try with `%-8x` and capital `X`. and observe the effect

Comment: Even though `8` and `0` are both numbers (and thus identical parts of a grammar in the English language) they are different parts of the printf format grammar. `0` is a "flag" and `8` is a parameter to "width" (which can be `<ε (no input)>`, `<d (any number greater than 0)>`, or `* (a literal asterisk)`). It is a non-intuitive API for sure! But what can you say... that's all old-style C stuff, where memory was such a premium that you wanna save AS many chars in a program as possible - I agree with their decision given the constraints they faced!

Comment: I do think it's an interesting question to ponder, though. How would you redesign the `printf` syntax? I love using `%` as the escape character, it's so unique and niche to string formatting. I think modifiers should be *appended* rather than prepended, though - that way you can read it left to right. Something like `%<specifier>[%f<flags>][%-w<width>.<precision>]%`, instead of `%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier`. I chose a `%` between each field, as well as one to close (so you can still do `%x%x` - `%x%%x%) and allows for a multi-char specifier

Answer (score 8):

`%08x` means that every number should be printed at least 8 characters wide with filling all missing digits with zeros, e.g. for '1' output will be `00000001`

Answer (score 4):

The format string attack on printf you mentioned isn't specific to the "%x" formatting - in any case where printf has more formatting parameters than passed variables, it will read values from the stack that do not belong to it. You will get the same issue with %d for example.
%x is useful when you want to see those values as hex.

As explained in previous answers, %08x will produce a 8 digits hex number, padded by preceding zeros.

Using the formatting in your code example in printf, with no additional parameters:

```
printf ("%08x %08x %08x %08x");
```

Will fetch 4 parameters from the stack and display them as 8-digits padded hex numbers.

Answer (score 2):

That specifies the how many digits you want it to show.

> integer value or * that specifies minimum field width. The result is padded with space characters (by default), if required, on the left when right-justified, or on the right if left-justified. In the case when * is used, the width is specified by an additional argument of type int. If the value of the argument is negative, it results with the - flag specified and positive field width.

Answer (score 2):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string

use 0 instead of spaces to pad a field when the width option is specified. For example, `printf("%2d", 3)` results in " 3", while `printf("%02d", 3)` results in "03".