# Format specifier %02x

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

I have a simple program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        long i = 16843009;
        printf ("%02x \n" ,i);
}
```

I am using `%02x` format specifier to get 2 char output,
However, the output I am getting is:

```
1010101
```

while I am expecting it to be :`01010101` .

Answer (score 65):

`%02x` means print at least 2 digits, prepend it with `0`'s if there's less. In your case it's 7 digits, so you get no extra `0` in front.

Also, `%x` is for int, but you have a long. Try `%08lx` instead.

Comment: I have learnt that 'x' in '%x' refers to hexadecimal format and not int. Is it so?

Comment: `x` refers to "integer in hexadecimal format" as opposed to `d` which is "integer in decimal format". Both accept `int` as a value to be printed. `lx` and `ld` both accept `long`.

Comment: For the sake of completenes also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108932/c-the-x-format-specifier and  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: "Both accept int as a value to be printed" --> Hmmm, `"%x"` is for `unsigned`, not `int`.  Common enough that `int` "works" though, even if not specified by C.

Answer (score 17):

`%x` is a format specifier that format and output the hex value. If you are providing int or long value, it will convert it to hex value.

`%02x` means if your provided value is less than two digits then `0` will be prepended.

You provided value `16843009` and it has been converted to `1010101` which a hex value.

Answer (score 2):

Your string is wider than your format width of 2. So there's no padding to be done.

Answer (score -3):

You are actually getting the correct value out.

The way your `x86` (compatible) processor stores data like this, is in **Little Endian** order, meaning that, the MSB is last in your output.

So, given your output:

> 10101010

the last two hex values `10` are the Most Significant Byte (`2 hex digits = 1 byte = 8 bits` (for (possibly unnecessary) clarification).

So, by **reversing** the memory storage order of the bytes, your value is actually:  `01010101`.

Hope that clears it up!

Comment: Uh no, printf is not printing the MSB to the right, that would be pretty confusing

Comment: Besides what eckes said, bit numbering inside of most processors isn't really a thing because you generally deal with a byte at a time. Bit ordering matters only for serialization. Endianness (big or little) is byte ordering, not bit ordering.