# I can't understand "String.format() function in this example any help ?"

Tags: java

this an example to get mac address form my machine but i can't understand the syntax of sting.format function 
here is the example.

```java
public String getMACIdentifier(NetworkInterface network)
{
    StringBuilder identifier = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        byte[] macBuffer = network.getHardwareAddress();
        if (macBuffer != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < macBuffer.length; i++) {
                identifier.append(
                    String.format("%02X%s",macBuffer[i],
                    (i < macBuffer.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));
            }
        } else {
            return "---";
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return identifier.toString();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format specifier %02x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438946/format-specifier-02x)

Comment: Did you **read the documentation** on [`String.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-), leading you to the full description of the [**format string**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)?

Answer (score 2):

Formatted strings are a common feature of programming languages. I would recommend [reading up](http://java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Data_Format/Java_Format_Specifier.htm) on how they work in Java.

In your specific example, the format string `"%02X%s"` will print a hexadecimal number (represented by `%02X`) next to a string (represented by `"%s"`). The hex number will be printed using *at least* 2 characters; if the number is representable with just one character, then the empty space will be "padded" with a '0' character. This is coded `"%02X"`. The string character will be either `"-"` or `""` (*empty*), depending on the result of the ternary operator (`test ? true_value : false_value`).

Comment: *"using **up to** 2 characters"* is wrong, it means *at least* 2 characters. --- Also, `""` is not *null*, it's an *empty* string. Null is something entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder identifier = new StringBuilder();
    byte[] macBuffer = new byte[5];

    macBuffer[0] = 0x10;
    macBuffer[1] = 0x1;
    macBuffer[2] = 0x02;
    macBuffer[3] = 0x30;

    for (int i = 0; i < macBuffer.length; i++) {
        identifier.append(
                String.format("%02X%s", macBuffer[i],
                        (i < macBuffer.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));
    }

    System.out.println(identifier.toString());
}
```

Output

```
10-01-02-30-00
```

`"%02X%s"`

- `%02X` this is for hexadecimal format and the `02` refer to the minimum number of chars (`0x1` is printed as `0x01`)
- `%s` this is for string format