# What refers to %04x in python unicode characteristics?

Tags: python, unicode

```
print(i, '%04x' % ord(c), unicodedata.category(c), end=" " )
```

In the above code what refers to `%04x`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C - The %x format specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108932/c-the-x-format-specifier)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't have anything directly to do with Unicode. `%04x` is a *format specifier*, which only makes sense with the `%` operator. It specifies that the number to be formatted (in this case, `ord(c)`) should be formatted as a hexadecimal with four digits and zero-padding on the left. So if `c` is `"A"`, whose Unicode code point is 65, it will be printed as `0041`.

Comment: Thanks for this, really it makes me clear on format specifier as you mention

Comment: what about :04x ?

Comment: @ShreyanMehta Sorry, what is the context of that? `:04x` has no special meaning to the `%` operator. If you arrived at this question when searching for something Unicode-related, this answer doesn't deal with that because the question wasn't actually about something Unicode-specific but about something Python-specific.

Comment: No it was not about unicode, I got a python string format error , in which in string {:04x} is there but when i tried that without 0 it gave same results ,

Comment: @ShreyanMehta That format specifier only works with `format()`, not with `%`. So e.g. `print("{:04x}".format(ord("A")))` works, and prints `0041`. If that doesn't fix your problem, please post a separate question, including the error message you're getting and a minimal example that reproduces the error.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, I appreciate it. Well i think a seperate question would be needed for that, since we are on a bit different pages. But thats fine, I made a work around and I dont need it anymore, just posted for knowledge sake, though python not my daily driver language so its fine for me. Thanks