# Why am I getting a character in output when my input is 5 or more than 5? It is pure mathematical equation. If anything is wrong please tell me

Tags: c

I have compiled this code and it works just fine up to value 4 then it starts returning character instead of integer. I am talking about first equation => x= num*2; Here when I enter num value as 5 the output returns a.

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main(void)
{ 
    int num;
    int x;  This right here is an integer still it returns a  character
    char s[10] = "helloworld";
    char f[10];
    scanf("%d", &num);                          // 
    //printf("%d\n", num); 
    x = num * 2 ;
    printf("%x\n", x); 
    scanf("%c", &f[10]);
    if(s[10] = f[10]){
        printf("helloworld");
    }
}
```

please tell me if there is a mistake I am a newbie to coding.

Comment: for starters, `char s[10] = "helloworld";` is too small, you didn't leave room for the `NUL` terminator, that needs to be `s[11]` at least.

Comment: thank you yano. sure i will correct it

Comment: Also for an array of ten elements like `f`, `f[10]` will be out of bounds as it uses the *eleventh* element.

Comment: And `s[10] = f[10` is doing *assignment* and not comparison.

Comment: And the main problem seems to be that you don't understand [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) notation. All in all it seems you're learning C by guessing. Get a few books and take some classes.

Comment: Short answer: [turn on compiler warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/jsbz45bKj) and _read them_.  Your compiler wants to tell you about these mistakes.

Comment: What do you think it should print?

Comment: @stark as I enter num value 5 it should print 10 .

Comment: @yash Not with base 16.

Comment: @YashRaval your `%x` indicates that you want the number [printed in hexadecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108932/c-the-x-format-specifier).  In hexadecimal notation, the number after `9` is the number `a`.

Answer (score 1):

- As I see you are learning C language, and after reading your explanation, I feel that you want to print the integer value of variable x.

> Kindly replace `%x` with `%d` in the print statement of variable x,
> and you will be successfully able to print the value.

```
#include <stdio.h>    

int main(void)
{ 
    int num;
    int x;  // This right here is an integer still it returns a  character
    char s[10] = "helloworld";
    char f[10];
    scanf("%d", &num);
    x = num * 2 ;
    printf("%d\n", x);   // %d for integer and %x for hexadecimal values
    scanf("%c", &f[10]);
    if(s[10] = f[10]){
    printf("helloworld");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

- Finally, do read more about [format specifiers](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) in scanf and
  printf statements.